# Таблица с циклом с несколькими уровнями вложенности с помощью docxtpl

Tags: python, jinja2, python-docx, docxtpl

Я пытаюсь создать Word-документ с помощью python-docx-template, в нём должна быть таблица с объединёнными ячейками. Я формирую такой контекст, логика в том, что у каждого элемента есть текстовое название и массив дочерних элементов. Данные беру из базы и могу преобразовывать как угодно.

```
context = {'table_rows': 
[
    {'item': 'target1', 'activities': [
        {'item': 'activity1', 'outputs': [
            {'item': 'Output1', 'shortoutcomes': [
                #midoutcomes и impacts аналогично
            ]}
        ]},
        {'item': 'activity2', 'outputs': []}
    ]},
    {'item': 'target2', 'activities': []}
]}
```

Далее я пытаюсь, используя это в это в шаблоне, получить таблицу в ворде

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate, RichText
#что-то
doc = DocxTemplate(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, "templateprogram.docx"))
doc.render(context)
```

Таблицу хочу с объединёнными ячейками, чтобы было видно, что из какого массива, примерно такую. Если посмотреть на Output, ShotrOutcome, MidOutcome и Impact, чётко видно, что к чему относится
[image]

И я не могу составить такой шаблон, самое близкое, что у меня получалось, это вот это, потому что тут хотя бы общая высота таблицы соответствует ожиданиям
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь использовался такой шаблон
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пыталась экспериментировать с `{% vm %}` и заметила, что эффект он даёт, только если в одной ячейке он есть, а в соседней его нет (мой случай с последними двумя столбцами). При этом использовать как-то более одного `{% vm %}` в ячейке у меня не получилось.

Также я изучала такого рода шаблоны
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конкретно этот выдавал такую таблицу, что мне никак не подходит, но это самое лучшее, что было
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Если тут использовать `tr` во всех циклах, то данные будут только в последнем столбце, что логично и понятно, почему документация это не рекомендует.

Вообще [документацию](https://docxtpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) читала безумное количество раз, и там в том числе написано, что всё, что можно сделать с вордом, можно и с помощью этого пакета. Значит должен быть способ решить и эту проблему? :)

На гитхабе подходящих примеров не нашла, там везде только 1 вложенный цикл, а у меня 5.

Я не очень хорошо знаю питон, а с пакетом `docxtpl` вообще не сталкивалась до этого задания, но это задание - маленький пункт в рамках очень большого, и со всем остальным я уже справилась.

Этот пакет использую только потому, что он использовался в проекте до того, как я за него взялась, и используется там для других документов тоже. Но если есть идеи, как реализовать это с помощью чего-то другого, я их тоже рассматриваю.

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего не поддерживается в `python-docx-template`.
По крайней мере, я нашёл только эту информацию 2019 года.
https://github.com/elapouya/python-docx-template/issues/172

> Dynamic vertical merging (based on cell content) is not supported in docxtpl

---

Но если использовать `python-docx`, то, судя по [документации](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/features/table/cell-merge.html), там можно объединять любые ячейки:

```
table = document.add_table(3, 3)
a = table.cell(0, 0)
b = table.cell(1, 1)
A = a.merge(b)
```

```
\ 0   1   2   3
0 +---+---+---+        +---+---+---+
  | a |   |   |        | A     |   |
1 +---+---+---+        + - - - +---+
  |   | b |   |  -->   | ^     |   |
2 +---+---+---+        +---+---+---+
  |   |   |   |        |   |   |   |
3 +---+---+---+        +---+---+---+
```

Comment: Теоретически из подготовленного DocxTemplate можно вытащить документ ([метод get_docx](https://github.com/elapouya/python-docx-template/blob/8a3c2051ad06d88aa643fd64e22ed8ddd9796e82/docxtpl/template.py#L64)), найти в нем таблицу и смержить ячейки как нужно, но это довольно извращенно получится